# あるファイルが保存されたタイミングで、特定のコマンドを実行したい

Tags: emacs

あるファイルを save したタイミングで、特定のコマンドを実行したいとします。
(`hoge-command target-file` を実行したいです。)
(ファイルをデプロイ先サーバーに反映させるためのコマンドを用意する想定)

これを実現するにはどうしたらいいでしょうか。

flymake が雰囲気、これを実現できそうだ、と考えたのですが、いまいちこれを実現するための設定 (だけ) を明確に記述した資料を見つけられずにいるので、質問しています。

Comment: `after-save-hook` を利用するとか。

Answer (score 1):

metropolisさんが書かれている通り、
after-save-hookを使用するのが良いと思います。

単にafter-save-hookに関数を登録すると、
どんなバッファで保存してもその関数呼ばれてしまうので、
add-hookで登録する時、buffer localになるようにするとか、
登録した関数内で判定処理を入れるといった工夫が必要だと思います。

```
 (add-hook HOOK FUNCTION &optional APPEND LOCAL)
```

このへんがお望みの回答に近そうです。
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6138029/how-to-add-a-hook-to-only-run-in-a-particular-mode